# Write a row to Google Spreadsheet programmatically javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a way to insert a row into a google spreadsheet dynamically.  I have  a list of objects that has all the data for every column in a row.  I'm just trying to run a for loop and then send the data to the row in the spread sheet.  But the spreadsheet is completely empty.  So I don't know if that creates certain problems or not.

```
  for(var j=0; j < masterList.length; j++) {

        //tried this one but it didn't pan out
       sheet.appendRow([ masterList[j].Date, masterList[j].Name, masterList[j].Bugs,      masterList[j].Enhancements, masterList[j].Epic, masterList[j].DevOps, masterList[j].High ]);


   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you accessing the spreadsheet and then the sheet before trying to append it? Here is an example.

```
function insertData(masterList) {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

    for(var j=0; j < masterList.length; j++) {
        var ml = masterList[j];
        sheet.appendRow( [ ml.Date, ml.Name, ml.Bugs, ml.Enhancements, ml.Epic, ml.DevOps, ml.High ] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have that in my code actually.  Well I did then I took it out.  But my script is rather large and I found out that something else was wrong, not the sheet.appendRow().  The debugger takes forever to run, plus I have 200 or so checks to a Trello API that returns Json objects so I didn't catch this until just recently  thanks for the help though.

Comment: One thing that can help is creating a file for each set of functions that essentially behaves like a class. Then you can test them without running the whole program, and have the added benefit of making that ode easy to use in another project. The project is essentially a namespace, so adding a file is like importing a class. I like to use the format of creating a file, lets call it Test.js, and then defining it's 'class' using var Test = function(){. Now you can call Test from any other file in the project, and any functions or variable in it become children.